# Can't set file type icon on macOS

Tags: macos

I'm using `CFBundleDocumentTypes` key in `Info.plist` file for this.

My app is associated with file type and is launched when I double click. It's also shown as a default one in Open With menu when I right click on a file in Finder.

However, icon is not changed to the one specified in my `Info.plist`. Files with this extension still has no icon.

My `Info.plist` is the following:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
            <array>
                <string>torrent</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>icon.icns</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>BitTorrent Document</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
            <false/>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Owner</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
            <string>org.bittorrent.torrent</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: I think you will have better luck asking in [apple.se].

Comment: @SiKing I disagree, it looks like a programming question, not a user question to me.

Comment: Maybe try re-registering the app using lsregister: https://eclecticlight.co/2019/03/25/lsregister-a-valuable-undocumented-command-for-launchservices/

Comment: @JWWalker lregister did not help...

Comment: To check the obvious, is there a file `Contents/Resources/icon.icns` in your application?  And does it open correctly in Preview?

Comment: @JWWalker Yes, it's the app's main icon.